# Limited available font support

Tags: phpstorm

I have monaco font and I would want to use it in php storm 6.03. But I don't know how. It doesn't list in avaiable font but I have the font installed.

Answer (score 2):

Try unchecking the 'show only monospaced fonts' otherwise check if the font isnt damaged.

I had the same issue unchecking that should work.

Comment: 'Show only monspaced fonts' cannot be unchecked and the fonts cannot be changed as well as the line spacing. I have even switched to 7.0 and still having the same problem.

Comment: could this because I am using a trial version? The 'Show only monspaced fonts' is there but I cannot uncheck it.

Answer (score 1):

1. create your own theme. by clicking on "Save As" button. INput your custom name  and Uncheck "show only monospaced fonts". after that the user will have the ability to change the following.
2. font

2.size

3.line spacing.

Comment: I have tried it and it does not work in PHPStorm 8.1